# C# Array Move Item (Not ArrayList/Generic List)

Tags: c#, arrays

Have an object which is an array (not arraylist or generic) that could hold a set of anything...

```
[[One],[Two],[Three],[Four]]
```

Want to move [Four] to in front of [Two] e.g.
oldIndex = 3, newIndex = 1
so the result would be...

```
[[One],[Four][Two],[Three]]
```

Whats the most effient way to do this in .NET 2.0,
e.g.

```
PropertyInfo oPI = ObjectType.GetProperty("MyArray", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
object ObjectToReorder = oPI.GetValue(ParentObject, null);
Array arr = ObjectToReorder as Array;
int oldIndex = 3;
int newIndex = 1;
//Need the re-ordered list still attached to the ParentObject
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
void MoveWithinArray(Array array, int source, int dest)
{
  Object temp = array.GetValue(source);
  Array.Copy(array, dest, array, dest + 1, source - dest);
  array.SetValue(temp, dest);
}
```

Comment: thats more like it, just goes to show that its not about how many questions you've answered its about how good the answers are.
I had no idea you could copy an array onto itself.
I guess thats how the ArrayList does Insert?,i tried the code using reflector but I could find the ArrayList class
thanks

Comment: That question looks like it was too easy for you, if you can could you try to answer this other question i've posted...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/668356/use-reflection-to-set-the-value-of-a-field-in-a-struct-which-is-part-of-an-array

Comment: I really don't understand how this answer can get any up-votes at all. The solution given here only works in OP's very specific example. The method should be named `MoveWithinArrayInOneSpecificCase(...)`. For example, if we try to move an element from front to back we get negative `length`-parameter (just one of the possible errors in this method).

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
Array someArray = GetTheArray();
object temp = someArray.GetValue(3);
someArray.SetValue(someArray.GetValue(1), 3);
someArray.SetValue(temp, 1);
```

Comment: If I step through your code with the array i gave then i get a different array to the one I required...
###
1. Array someArray = GetTheArray();
[[One],[Two],[Three],[Four]]
###
2. object temp = someArray.GetValue(3);
[[One],[Two],[Three],[Four]]
temp is [Four]
###
3. someArray.SetValue(someArray.GetValue(1), 3);
someArray.GetValue(1) is [Two]
[[One],[Two],[Three],**[Two]**]
###
4. someArray.SetValue(temp, 1);
[[One],**[Four]**,[Three],[Two]]
###
I wanted [[One],[Four],[Two],[Three]] (i.e. Move [Four] in-front of [Two])