# Set value of private field

Tags: c#, reflection

Why is the following code not working:

```c#
class Program
{
    static void Main ( string[ ] args )
    {
        SomeClass s = new SomeClass( );

        s.GetType( ).GetField( "id" , System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic ) // sorry reasently updated to GetField from GetProperty...
            .SetValue( s , "new value" );
    }
}


class SomeClass
{
    object id;

    public object Id 
    {
        get
        {
            return id;
        }
    }   
}
```

I am trying to set the value of a private field.

---

Here is the exeption I get:

```
 System.NullReferenceException was unhandled   Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.   Source=ConsoleApplication7
 StackTrace:
        at Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Antonio\Desktop\ConsoleApplication7\ConsoleApplication7\Program.cs:line 18
        at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
        at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
        at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
        at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
        at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
        at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
        at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()   InnerException:
```

Comment: Could you specify "not working"? What happens, and how does that differ from what you expect? Do you get any error message?

Comment: Try itterating through GetFields() (manually using debugger breakpoint) to see what is returned. Afaik, there is no guarantee that the variable id will stay named id, but I'm not sure. Also, I've had problems getting private properties/methods before, and it's generally solved by using BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance (for instance)

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Try this (inspired by [Find a private field with Reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95910/find-a-private-field-with-reflection)):

```
var prop = s.GetType().GetField("id", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic
    | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
prop.SetValue(s, "new value");
```

My changes were to use the `GetField` method - you are accessing a field and not a property, and to or `NonPublic` with `Instance`.

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work for structures.
it seams to set value of structure copy sent to SetValue, and original structure remains unchanged.

Comment: According to Jon Skeet, the correct way to set a struct requires explicit boxing before calling SetValue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6280506/is-there-a-way-to-set-properties-on-struct-instances-using-reflection

Answer (score 2):

If you want a faster alternative consider using expression trees or `Unsafe.As<T>`. [In testing](https://youtu.be/AlI-lYmUOaA?t=366) reflection can be anywhere between 30x to 100x times slower than either technique.

##### Expression tree

```
static Action<TSource, TArg> BuildSetterExpression<TSource, TArg>(FieldInfo field)
{
    var inputObject = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource));
    var valueToSet = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TArg));

    var fieldInformation = Expression.Field(inputObject, field);
    var fieldAssignment = Expression.Assign(fieldInformation, valueToSet);

    return Expression.Lambda<Action<TSource, TArg>>(fieldAssignment, inputObject, valueToSet).Compile();
}

var fieldInfo = typeof(MyClass).GetField("_num", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
var setNumFunc = BuildSetterExpression<MyClass, int>(fieldInfo);

var instance = new MyClass();
setNumFunc(instance, 123);
Assert.Equal(123, instance.Num);

class MyClass
{
    private int _num = 12;
    public int Num => _num;
}
```

##### Unsafe.As<T>

If you know the structure of the object you're accessing and don't mind using unsafe code use `Unsafe.As<T>`

```
var source = new SourceClass();
var target = Unsafe.As<TargetClass>(source);

target.Num = 123;
Assert.Equal(123, source.GetPrivateNum);

class SourceClass
{
    private int _num = 12;
    public int GetPrivateNum => _num;
}

class TargetClass
{
    public int Num { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Evidently, adding `BindingFlags.Instance` seems to have solved it:

```
> class SomeClass
  {
      object id;

      public object Id
      {
          get
          {
              return id;
          }
      }
  }
> var t = typeof(SomeClass)
      ;
> t
[Submission#1+SomeClass]
> t.GetField("id")
null
> t.GetField("id", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
> t.GetField("id", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)
[System.Object id]
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending Nick's answer:

```
    public static void SetPrivateField<T, T2>(this T item, string fieldName, T2 newValue)
    {
        var field = item.GetType().GetField(fieldName, BindingFlags.NonPublic, | BindingFlags.Instance);
        field.SetValue(item, newValue);
    }
```

To use this:

```
someClassInstance.SetPrivateField("id", "newValue");
//realizes the type T2 by the fact "newValue" is a string.
//probably doesn't work on readonly, haven't tried.
```