# Can a CryptoStream leave the base Stream open?

Tags: c#, stream, objectdisposedexception

I create a `MemoryStream`, pass it to `CryptoStream` for writing.  I want the `CryptoStream` to encrypt, and leave the `MemoryStream` open for me to then read into something else.  But as soon as `CryptoStream` is disposed, it disposes of `MemoryStream` too.

Can `CryptoStream` leave the base `MemoryStream` open somehow?

```
using (MemoryStream scratch = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (AesManaged aes = new AesManaged())
    {
        // <snip>
        // Set some aes parameters, including Key, IV, etc.
        // </snip>
        ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor();
        using (CryptoStream myCryptoStream = new CryptoStream(scratch, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            myCryptoStream.Write(someByteArray, 0, someByteArray.Length);
        }
    }
    // Here, I'm still within the MemoryStream block, so I expect
    // MemoryStream to still be usable.
    scratch.Position = 0;    // Throws ObjectDisposedException
    byte[] scratchBytes = new byte[scratch.Length];
    scratch.Read(scratchBytes,0,scratchBytes.Length);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(scratchBytes);
}
```

Comment: Why are you using streams in the first place? Just call `encryptor.TransformFinalBlock` on the input bytes. Streams are mostly useful for incremental encryption/decryption but not when you have the full data available at the same time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can but you will not be able to use using statements. You will need to manually manage the disposing of the object and  you will also need to call [`FlushFinialBlock()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream.flushfinalblock%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to make sure all the data was written out to the underlying stream before working on it.

Once all you are done working with the stream you can then dispose all of the resources you where waiting on in the finally block at the end.

```
MemoryStream scratch = null;
AesManaged aes = null;
CryptoStream myCryptoStream = null;
try
{
    scratch = new MemoryStream();
    aes = new AesManaged();

    // <snip>
    // Set some aes parameters, including Key, IV, etc.
    // </snip>
    ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor();
    myCryptoStream = new CryptoStream(scratch, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
    myCryptoStream.Write(someByteArray, 0, someByteArray.Length);

    //Flush the data out so it is fully written to the underlying stream.
    myCryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

    scratch.Position = 0; 
    byte[] scratchBytes = new byte[scratch.Length];
    scratch.Read(scratchBytes,0,scratchBytes.Length);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(scratchBytes);
}
finally
{
    //Dispose all of the disposeable objects we created in reverse order.

    if(myCryptoStream != null)
        myCryptoStream.Dispose();

    if(aes != null)
        aes.Dispose();

    if(scratch != null)
        scratch.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: To the person who gave me a -1 what about my answer did you consider "not useful" to warrant a -1? If there is incorrect information in my post please inform me so I can correct or remove it. I guess the fact that the way the code is written the inner `try-finally` is unnecessary. I will remove it. The only other thing I can think of is the fact that `aes` and `scratch` get disposed before `myCryptoStream`. I will correct that also.

Comment: What if you want to write a method that returns the base stream after it has been encrypted and dispose the CryptoStream before returning the base stream? Does it matter if you dispose the CryptoStream? or is it fine to just dispose the BaseStream when your done with it?

Comment: Downvoted: Doesn't address how to return the base stream from the method in which the CryptoStream is used

Comment: CryptoStream Dispose method will still dispose the underlying stream. you still get duplicated dispose. You are just deferring it to the finally block. The correct answer is below with .NET version 4.7.2 new constructor overload.

Answer (score 19):

As of .NET 4.7.2, there is a second constructor with an added bool parameter called `leaveOpen`. If this is set to true then the `CryptoStream`'s dispose method will not call dispose on the underlying stream.

[Additionally](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/cryptostream.cs,330d087abc7bf5a4), the other constructor without the `leaveOpen` parameter simply forwards the parameters to the new constructor with `leaveOpen` set to `false`.

<s>MSDN</s> [MS Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-security-cryptography-cryptostream-ctor(system-io-stream-system-security-cryptography-icryptotransform-system-security-cryptography-cryptostreammode-system-boolean))
[`CryptoStream.Dispose(bool disposing)`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/3bb570e73c03705d.html)

This constructor is not present in .NET Standard 2.0, but the underlying field can be set with reflection (thanks @StuartLC for linking [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12993962/set-value-of-private-field/12994027#12994027,) in the comments):

```
using CryptoStream s = new(scratch, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)
var prop = s.GetType().GetField("leaveOpen", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
prop.SetValue(s, true);
```

This is a filthy workaround and I wouldn't recommend it unless you know the systems your software will run on have the relevant version of .NET installed.

Comment: +1 For some weird reason, I wasn't able to invoke this overload of the constructor, however, I was able to set the `_leaveOpen` flag [via Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12994027) with the same effect

Comment: @StuartLC were you writing a .NET Standard 2.0 library by any chance? The additional constructor is not part of .NET Standard 2.0 as it would break backwards compatibility with .NET Framework 4.6.1 where the constructor does not exist.

Comment: @StuartLC Thanks for the tip! It's a terribly dirty workaround, but since we're not gonna migrate soon to .Net Core and our software is guaranteed to run at 4.7.2 and above, it's the only way to get this working. I don't get why this wasn't added prior anyway. There's enough scenarios where you actually have to encrypt but continue using the stream (since the CryptoStream doesn't allow seeking).

Answer (score 15):

As a second solution, you can make a WrapperStream object that simply passes every call along except for Dispose / Close. Make a wrapper around your memory stream, hand the wrapper to the crypto stream, and now closing the crypto stream does not touch the memory stream.

Answer (score 7):

My simple solution:

```
class NotClosingCryptoStream : CryptoStream
{
    public NotClosingCryptoStream( Stream stream, ICryptoTransform transform, CryptoStreamMode mode )
        : base( stream, transform, mode )
    {
    }

    protected override void Dispose( bool disposing )
    {
        if( !HasFlushedFinalBlock )
            FlushFinalBlock();

        base.Dispose( false );
    }
}
```

Comment: it works, but i have a question: as MSDN mention
`disposing
Type: System.Boolean
true to release both managed and unmanaged resources; false to release only unmanaged resources`.

But as i know, Stream objects is unmanaged objects, so how can this solution prevent CryptoStream not release underlying stream ?

Answer (score 4):

It turns out, there isn't any need to break apart the using {} block into try{}finally{} ...  Ultimately, you just have to use FlushFinalBlock() inside the using statement, and nest anything else inside there as necessary.

```
using (MemoryStream scratch = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (AesManaged aes = new AesManaged())
    {
        // <snip>
        // Set some aes parameters, including Key, IV, etc.
        // </snip>
        ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor();
        using (CryptoStream myCryptoStream = new CryptoStream(scratch, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            myCryptoStream.Write(someByteArray, 0, someByteArray.Length);
            myCryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
            scratch.Flush();   // not sure if this is necessary
            byte[] scratchBytes = scratch.ToArray();
            return Convert.ToBase64String(scratchBytes);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `scrach.Flush()` is indeed unnessasary, [from the msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.flush.aspx) "*Overrides the Stream.Flush method so that no action is performed.*"