# Can a CryptoStream be returned and still have everything dispose correctly?

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, stream, dispose

If I have a `CryptoStream` that I want to pass back to the user, the naïve approach would be

```
public Stream GetDecryptedFileStream(string inputFile, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
{
    var fsCrypt = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
    var rmCrypto = new RijndaelManaged();
    var transform = rmCrypto.CreateDecryptor(key, iv);
    var cs = new CryptoStream(fsCrypt, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Read);

    return cs;
}
```

I know that when I dispose the `CryptoStream` the underlying `FileStream` [will also be disposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19736631/can-a-cryptostream-leave-the-base-stream-open). The issue I am running in to is what do I do with `rmCrypto` and `transform`? `RijndaelManaged` and `ICryptoTransform` are disposable classes, but disposing of the stream does not dispose those two objects.

What is the correct way to handle this situation?

Comment: According to your method, `rmCrypto` and `transform` should be disposed after you return from `GetDecryptedFileStream` as they are local variables in your method.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Going out of scope does not mean being disposed. The GC will not finalize those two objects until the last reference to `cs` is released.

Comment: Oh, i failed to see your `CryptoStream` is accepting them as a parameter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd consider creating your own class that wraps the stream and then you can manage the disposal of these. Somethings along these lines (sorry - don't know the type of the transform object off top of my head).

```
public CryptoStreamWrapper : Stream, IDisposable
{
    public CryptoStreamWrapper(CryptoStream stream, RijndaelManaged rmCrypto, IDisposable transform)
    {
        this.transform = transform;
        this.rmCrypto = rmCrypto;
        this.stream = stream;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.transform.Dispose();
        this.rmCrypto.Dispose();
        this.stream.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, That is very similar to the solution I came up with after asking the question after "asking my duck". You can derive `CryptoStream`. I will post a answer.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: I love the fact you're using rubber ducking!

Comment: Great solution, was about to post that exact thing

Comment: Why does it inherit from `Stream`?

Comment: @ken2k: Because this allows the consumer to use it as though it were a stream. They don't need to know that it's some special class that does other stuff. You'd then pipe all the calls through to the base stream.

Comment: @Ian I get the overall idea, but inheriting from `CryptoStream` would be more simple as you wouldn't have to first instantiate it _then_ a wrapper. This kinda adds another encapsulation level, as the wrappers now _owns_ the CryptoStream.

Comment: @ken2k: You're correct. I hadn't realised that CryptoStream wasn't sealed and ScottChamberlain picked up on that a little later and added his own answer. I've not updated mine to reflect the effort he's put in to improve on my answer.

Answer (score 12):

Ian beat me to the basic concept ([go upvote him](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24188769/80274)), but CryptoStream itself is not sealed so it is trivial to make a derived class that wraps the things that need to be disposed.

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates a class that creates a <see cref="CryptoStream"/> and wraps the disposing action of all the associated objects 
/// </summary>
class ReturnableCryptoStream : CryptoStream
{
    private readonly ICryptoTransform _transform;
    private readonly IDisposable _algorithm;

    public ReturnableCryptoStream(Stream stream, ICryptoTransform transform, CryptoStreamMode mode) 
        : this(stream, transform, mode, null)
    {
    }

    public ReturnableCryptoStream(Stream stream, ICryptoTransform transform, CryptoStreamMode mode, IDisposable algorithm) 
        : base(stream, transform, mode)
    {
        _transform = transform;
        _algorithm = algorithm;
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (_transform != null)
                _transform.Dispose();

            if (_algorithm != null)
                _algorithm.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Used like

```
public Stream GetDecryptedFileStream(string inputFile, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
{
    var fsCrypt = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
    var rmCrypto = new RijndaelManaged();
    var transform = rmCrypto.CreateDecryptor(key, iv);
    var cs = new ReturnableCryptoStream(fsCrypt, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Read, rmCrypto);

    return cs;
}
```

Comment: Thinking about it, this is actually cleaner too, as you don't need to implement all the other members - like Length, ReadByte() etc.

Comment: I'm thinking that it might be more correct to do transform.Dispose() after the base.Dispose(), since the otherwise you're disposing somethign that the base class still has a reference too and might choose to make calls on during its disposal process. I'm not sure what your algorithm field is(?) If it's the original objectthat created the ICryptoTransform then that can be disposed of as soon as the ICryptoTransform is created, so you don't need to keep a ref to it for disposal later.

Comment: @locster I swaped the order of the dispose, you are right. Also you are correct that `algorithm` it is the thing that generated the `ICryptoTransform`. However, I did not see any documentation that said you are allowed to dispose the `SymmetricAlgorithm` derived class before you are done using the generated `ICryptoTransform` so I figured it is better to play it safe. If you do have any documentation that does say it I would love to have a definitive answer (Also you can pass `null` in if you want, it is only used to have `Dispose()` called on it).

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I can't find any documentation about early Dispose() of the SymmetricAlgorithm instances. From looking at the source it looks safe for AesManaged, but there's no guarantee that it's safe for all subclasses/implementations, or future implementations. Good call.