# Invalid attempt to call HasRows when reader is closed with ado.net wrapper class

Tags: c#, ado.net

I'm trying to write a wrapper class for ado.net, problem is I get the following error and I do not know how to solve it.

I have read many other question about this, but none use a wrapper class and as such are not helpful.

Can anyone point me in the right direction or supply a link with the same problem so i can read how to solve it. Or am I completely going about it the wrong way.

```
public List<LoginDetails> Authenticate(string id)
        {
            const string spName = "dbo.MemberLogin";
            List<SqlParameter> parameters = new List<SqlParameter> { new SqlParameter("@Username", id) };
            var rdr = _iAdoCommandWrapper.ExecuteDataReaderAsync(DbConnectionAbstractClass.ConnectionString, CommandType.StoredProcedure, spName, parameters.ToArray());
            var data = new List<LoginDetails>();
            if (rdr.HasRows)
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    data.Add(new LoginDetails
                    {
                        UserName = (string)rdr["MemberUsername"],
                        Password = (string)rdr["MemberPassword"],
                        MemberId = (string)rdr["MemberID"],
                        Role     = (string)rdr["MemberRole"]
                    });
                }
                //-------
                rdr.NextResult();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    data.Add(new LoginDetails
                    {
                        RolesForMember = (string)(rdr["MembersRoles"])
                    });
                }

                //----------
            }
            return data.ToList();// rowsAffected.Result;
        }
```

Wrapper

```
public SqlDataReader ExecuteDataReaderAsync(string connectionString, CommandType cmdType, string spName, params SqlParameter[] cmdParameters)
        {
            //TODO make async once fixed problem
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(spName, conn))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = cmdType;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddRange(cmdParameters);
                    conn.Open();
                    return cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.Default);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: The `rdr` is dependent on the SqlCommand (which is dependent on the SqlConnection). But both of those objects are disposed of before exiting the `ExecuteDataReaderAsync` method.

Comment: @Ulric how do i solve the problem

Comment: Phillpson  See below...again.

Comment: @Ulric sorry for delay, my internet went down

Answer (score 1):

`DataReader` actually has a behavior for just this situation, `CommandBehavior.CloseConnection`.

```
public SqlDataReader ExecuteDataReaderAsync(string connectionString, CommandType cmdType, string spName, params SqlParameter[] cmdParameters)
{
    // These two are intentionally are not in a using statement, but it is ok, closing 
    // the reader cleans up the resources.
    var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    var cmd = new SqlCommand(spName, conn))

    cmd.CommandType = cmdType;
    cmd.Parameters.AddRange(cmdParameters);
    conn.Open();
    return cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
}
```

When you dispose of the `DataReader` it will close the `SqlConnection` which is what disposing of the connection would do anyway (plus raise the `Disposed` event).

The only thing disposing of `SqlCommand` does is release the reference to a internal variable `_cachedMetaData` to allow it to get GC'ed earlier and call the base `Dispose(bool)` on `Component` which only thing it does is raise the `Disposed` event.

As long as you are not using the [`Disposed`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.disposed(v=vs.110).aspx) event of the connection or the command or the connection this solution should work for you.

---

If you really must "properly" dispose of the two because you do rely on the event, use a trick similar to what I did when [I ran in to a similar situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24188644/can-a-cryptostream-be-returned-and-still-have-everything-dispose-correctly/24188846#24188846) in disposing a `CryptoStream`. Make a wrapper that would dispose your connection and command when the reader was disposed.

```
sealed class CleaningDataReader : IDataReader
{
    private readonly IDataReader _reader;
    private readonly IDisposable[] _itemsToDispose;

    public CleaningDataReader(IDataReader reader, params IDisposable[] itemsToDispose)
    {
        if(reader == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("reader");
        _reader = reader;
        _itemsToDispose = itemsToDispose;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _reader.Dispose();

        if (_itemsToDispose != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in _itemsToDispose)
            {
                if(item != null)
                    item.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        _reader.Close();
    }

    public int Depth
    {
        get { return _reader.Depth; }
    }

    public int FieldCount
    {
        get { return _reader.FieldCount; }
    }

    public bool GetBoolean(int i)
    {
        return _reader.GetBoolean(i);
    }

    public byte GetByte(int i)
    {
        return _reader.GetByte(i);
    }

    public long GetBytes(int i, long fieldOffset, byte[] buffer, int bufferoffset, int length)
    {
        return _reader.GetBytes(i, fieldOffset, buffer, bufferoffset, length);
    }

    public char GetChar(int i)
    {
        return _reader.GetChar(i);
    }

    public long GetChars(int i, long fieldoffset, char[] buffer, int bufferoffset, int length)
    {
        return _reader.GetChars(i, fieldoffset, buffer, bufferoffset, length);
    }

    public IDataReader GetData(int i)
    {
        return _reader.GetData(i);
    }

    public string GetDataTypeName(int i)
    {
        return _reader.GetDataTypeName(i);
    }

    public DateTime GetDateTime(int i)
    {
        return _reader.GetDateTime(i);
    }

    public decimal GetDecimal(int i)
    {
        return _reader.GetDecimal(i);
    }

    public double GetDouble(int i)
    {
        return _reader.GetDouble(i);
    }

    public Type GetFieldType(int i)
    {
        return _reader.GetFieldType(i);
    }

    public float GetFloat(int i)
    {
        return _reader.GetFloat(i);
    }

    public Guid GetGuid(int i)
    {
        return _reader.GetGuid(i);
    }

    public short GetInt16(int i)
    {
        return _reader.GetInt16(i);
    }

    public int GetInt32(int i)
    {
        return _reader.GetInt32(i);
    }

    public long GetInt64(int i)
    {
        return _reader.GetInt64(i);
    }

    public string GetName(int i)
    {
        return _reader.GetName(i);
    }

    public int GetOrdinal(string name)
    {
        return _reader.GetOrdinal(name);
    }

    public DataTable GetSchemaTable()
    {
        return _reader.GetSchemaTable();
    }

    public string GetString(int i)
    {
        return _reader.GetString(i);
    }

    public object GetValue(int i)
    {
        return _reader.GetValue(i);
    }

    public int GetValues(object[] values)
    {
        return _reader.GetValues(values);
    }

    public bool IsClosed
    {
        get { return _reader.IsClosed; }
    }

    public bool IsDBNull(int i)
    {
        return _reader.IsDBNull(i);
    }

    public object this[int i]
    {
        get { return _reader[i]; }
    }

    public object this[string name]
    {
        get { return _reader[name]; }
    }

    public bool NextResult()
    {
        return _reader.NextResult();
    }

    public bool Read()
    {
        return _reader.Read();
    }

    public int RecordsAffected
    {
        get { return _reader.RecordsAffected; }
    }
}
```

used with

```
public IDataReader ExecuteDataReaderAsync(string connectionString, CommandType cmdType, string spName, params SqlParameter[] cmdParameters)
{
    // These two are intentionally are not in a using statement, but it is ok, closing 
    // the reader cleans up the resources.
    var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    var cmd = new SqlCommand(spName, conn))

    cmd.CommandType = cmdType;
    cmd.Parameters.AddRange(cmdParameters);
    conn.Open();
    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
    return new CleaningDataReader(reader, cmd, conn);
}
```

I still would go with the first approach unless you *REALLY* need the Disposed event fired.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I would go with Scott Chamberlain's solution. Looks good.

You would need to either move the SqlConnection/SqlCommand initialisation out of the `ExecuteDataReaderAsync` method (making the wrapper kinda pointless) or step through all the data, storing the values.

This is one way to do that:

```
public List<Dictionary<string, object>> ExecuteDataReaderAsync(string connectionString, CommandType cmdType, string spName, params SqlParameter[] cmdParameters) {
        //TODO make async once fixed problem
        var records = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
            conn.Open();
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(spName, conn)) {
                cmd.CommandType = cmdType;
                cmd.Parameters.AddRange(cmdParameters);
                using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.Default)) {
                    while (rdr.Read()) {
                       var record = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                       for (int fieldIndex = 0; fieldIndex < rdr.FieldCount; fieldIndex++) {
                          record.Add(rdr.GetName(fieldIndex), rdr.GetValue(fieldIndex));
                       }
                       records.Add(record);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return results;
    }
```

Unfortunately, I can't test this at the moment. But it should be close to being correct.