# CA2202: Object can be disposed of more than once

Tags: c#, cng

I'm getting the following warning in the following code snippet but I cannot understand why

> warning CA2202: Microsoft.Usage : Object 'memStream' can be disposed more than once in method 'Encrypt(string)'. To avoid generating a System.ObjectDisposedException you should not call Dispose more than one time on an object.

Code:

```
string Encrypt(string toEncrypt)
{
    byte[] key = ...
    byte[] iv = ...

    using (AesCng aes = new AesCng())
    using (ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(key, iv))
    using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
    using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
    {
        UTF7Encoding encoder = new UTF7Encoding();
        byte[] bytes = encoder.GetBytes(toEncrypt);

        cryptoStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

        return Convert.ToBase64String(memStream.ToArray());
    }
}
```

The `CryptoStream` object, to the best of my knowledge, does not dispose of the passed in `Stream` when it itself is disposed. So how is it possible that the variable `memStream` can be disposed of more than once?

Many thanks.

Comment: I am not 100%, but I think you're not supposed to call `FlushFinalBlock()` inside the block, the using should take care of that I _think_

Comment: That was Raymond Chen's "Old New Thing" yesterday: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20181126-00/?p=100325.  Not your case, exactly, but... The Stream APIs are notorious for IDisposable weirdnesses

Comment: Check the last parameter of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Security_Cryptography_CryptoStream__ctor_System_IO_Stream_System_Security_Cryptography_ICryptoTransform_System_Security_Cryptography_CryptoStreamMode_System_Boolean_ - https://stackoverflow.com/a/50878853/34092 (ignore the other answers, read the specific answer I linked to).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CryptoStream.Dispose()` will, by default, dispose the underlying stream. If you don't want that behavior you need to use the constructor [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Security_Cryptography_CryptoStream__ctor_System_IO_Stream_System_Security_Cryptography_ICryptoTransform_System_Security_Cryptography_CryptoStreamMode_System_Boolean_) that explicitly makes the underlying stream remain open when the `CryptoStream` is disposed.

You can see how that's implemented [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/cryptostream.cs,3bb570e73c03705d,references).

Comment: Ahh thanks... I looked into this and didn't realize `Close` was equivalent to `Dispose` for streams

Comment: I assume you meant to link to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Security_Cryptography_CryptoStream__ctor_System_IO_Stream_System_Security_Cryptography_ICryptoTransform_System_Security_Cryptography_CryptoStreamMode_System_Boolean_ rather than `Dispose`? I suspect your original suggestion won't compile.

Answer (score -1):

You can use overloaded CryptoStream constructor with leaveOpen parameter.

And no need this because CryptoStream object in using block

`cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();`

Code:

```
string Encrypt(string toEncrypt)
{
    byte[] key = ...
    byte[] iv = ...

    using (AesCng aes = new AesCng())
    using (ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(key, iv))
    using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
    using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write,true))
    {
        UTF7Encoding encoder = new UTF7Encoding();
        byte[] bytes = encoder.GetBytes(toEncrypt);

        cryptoStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

        return Convert.ToBase64String(memStream.ToArray());
    }
}
```

> leaveOpen: true to not close the underlying stream when the CryptoStream object is disposed

[CryptoStream ctor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Security_Cryptography_CryptoStream__ctor_System_IO_Stream_System_Security_Cryptography_ICryptoTransform_System_Security_Cryptography_CryptoStreamMode_System_Boolean_)

Comment: Also consider remove the `FlushFinalBlock` and moving the return outside of the `using` block (to make the code more concise).

Comment: You may want to read my comment again. Especially the second part of the sentence.