Cannot access closed stream wih CrypoStream
I'm building a file encryptor/decryptor utility using the .NET Framework 4.5, but when I'm finisched using the CrypyoStream to write to a destination stream, which will write the file to disk or serve as a memory stream to directly read the crypted file, the destination stream happens to be closed
Sub Crypt(ByRef destinationStream As System.IO.Stream) Implements IVersion.Crypt
    InitMetadataFromCryptStream()
    destinationStream.Write(_fileMetadata.GetBytes(), 0, _fileMetadata.Size)
    Using cryptStream As New CryptoStream(destinationStream, encAlgo.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write)
        _fileStream.CopyTo(cryptStream)
        cryptStream.FlushFinalBlock()
    End Using
End Sub

The InitMetadataFromCryptStream basically prepares a custom header for the file, while the encAlgo is an instance of Rijndael.
A working solution that I found was to copy the file onto a new MemoryStream and use it to initialize the CryptoStream, but it seems a big waste of memory and probably not the best option

Maybe you could use the other CryptoStream constructor? public CryptoStream (System.IO.Stream stream, System.Security.Cryptography.ICryptoTransform transform, System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode mode, bool leaveOpen);

@PresidentJamesK.Polk You forgot to specify the value of leaveOpen ;)

Ivan, most stream implementations will close all underlying streams by default.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk I cannot use that constructor because I'm currently working with a .NET Framework 4.5 application and the only one available is without the leaveOpen parameter
https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream.-ctor?view=netframework-4.5#system-security-cryptography-cryptostream-ctor(system-io-stream-system-security-cryptography-icryptotransform-system-security-cryptography-cryptostreammode-system-boolean)

Actually, it should be clear that if you are using such an old version, you should mention this in the question from the beginning! After all, support for .NET Framework 4.5 was discontinued in Jan 2016 (even 4.5.2 was stopped in Apr 2022), here.

Maybe this is interesting for you: Can a CryptoStream leave the base Stream open?

@Topaco That was it! Disposing only the unmanaged resources with a new class did the trick

As suggested by @Topaco, the fastest way to achieve the leaveOpen parameter logic introduced with the .NET Framework 4.7.2 was to create a new class that inherits the CrypoStream class and dispose only the unmanaged resources
ref. answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28057998/6419298
