# how to call a private method from dll?

Tags: c#

the dll has a private method how can I call this method from my application?

```
Public Class FormAcceptanceBid2018

    Public OpenType As ClassStorage.enumBidFormOpenType
    Public ItemID As Integer

    Private Sub FormAcceptanceBid2018_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

            ....

            If ItemID > 0 Then
                FillForExistingItem()
            Else
                FillFormNewItem()
            End If
            ...

        End Sub
End Class
```

If I make this method public then everything works like this

```
FormAcceptanceBid2018 accepBid = new FormAcceptanceBid2018();
                    accepBid.ItemID = idBid;
                    accepBid.OpenType = ClassStorage.enumBidFormOpenType.ExistingItem; 
                    accepBid.FormAcceptanceBid2018_Load(null, null);   


                    accepBid.SaveBid();
```

Found on the Internet what can be called through reflection but I don’t understand how to fill in the variables
accepBid.ItemID and
accepBid.OpenType

```
typeof(FormAcceptanceBid2018).GetMethod("FormAcceptanceBid2018_Load", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).Invoke(new FormAcceptanceBid2018(), null);
```

Comment: it's not a recursion, it's a [reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection)

Comment: in the answer that you suggested to me there is no explanation of how to call with variables

Comment: by _"with variables"_ do you mean _"with parameters"_ ?

Comment: yes, 
accepBid.ItemID = idBid;
                    accepBid.OpenType = ClassStorage.enumBidFormOpenType.ExistingItem;

Comment: oh, I see now. You mean _"how to set private fields values with reflection?"_. Just after 0.48 seconds of googling I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12994027/2716623)