# How to set a struct's field's field's value by reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection

For example, I have the following code:

```
public struct Struct1
{
    public int F1;
}

public struct Struct2
{
    public Struct1 S1;
}

Struct2 s2 = new Struct2();
```

How can I set the value of s2.S1.F1 by reflection? Thanks!

Comment: You need to learn what is reflection and how to use it. And the use it for this problem and come back here if you face any issue in that.

Comment: Why not a duplicate of [Is there a way to set properties on struct instances using reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6280506)?