# C# Shift element of array untill specific point, and pull specific element to front

Tags: c#, arrays

My problem is that I want to have a specific element in the array, copy it to another variable, shift the entire array right only up unto that element, and then put the element at the front. In a nice drawing, It'd look like this.

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
          ^

[0, 1, 2, null, 4, 5]
          ^ (3)

[null, 0, 1, 2, 4, 5]
             ^ (3)

[null, 0, 1, 2, 4, 5]
 ^ (3)

[3, 0, 1, 2, 4, 5]
 ^
```

I've already tried to use a for loop to bring the elements to the front and then insert the 3, but I fear that my way of doing it isn't the most efficient or fastest way.

Here's what I've tried.

```
        int elementAt = 3;
        int[] array = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        int mem = array[elementAt];
        for (int i = elementAt; i > 0; i--)
            array[i] = array[i - 1];
        array[0] = mem;
```

I'm suspecting something like Array.Copy could do it faster...?

EDIT:
Every single answer down below has their own uses in specific scenarios.
There is no definitive answer for this question, let these results let you choose which method to use.

```
iterations, index, arraysize
HIGH, HIGH, HIGH
Speed for ShiftRightAt: 6616, ticks: 28007912
Speed for shiftlist: 3556, ticks: 15054635
Speed for arrayCopy: 1742, ticks: 7376152
Speed for MoveValueToFront: 67, ticks: 285901
LOW, LOW, HIGH
Speed for ShiftRightAt: 0, ticks: 28
Speed for shiftlist: 42, ticks: 180476
Speed for arrayCopy: 33, ticks: 142717
Speed for MoveValueToFront: 0, ticks: 67
HIGH, LOW, HIGH
Speed for ShiftRightAt: 0, ticks: 1399
Speed for shiftlist: 3624, ticks: 15341777
Speed for arrayCopy: 3177, ticks: 13449012
Speed for MoveValueToFront: 0, ticks: 926
LOW, HIGH, HIGH
Speed for ShiftRightAt: 73, ticks: 311428
Speed for shiftlist: 41, ticks: 174652
Speed for arrayCopy: 18, ticks: 79768
Speed for MoveValueToFront: 65, ticks: 277266
HIGH, HIGH, LOW
Speed for ShiftRightAt: 0, ticks: 1379
Speed for shiftlist: 0, ticks: 3902
Speed for arrayCopy: 0, ticks: 728
Speed for MoveValueToFront: 0, ticks: 914
LOW, LOW, LOW
Speed for ShiftRightAt: 0, ticks: 3
Speed for shiftlist: 0, ticks: 32
Speed for arrayCopy: 0, ticks: 11
Speed for MoveValueToFront: 0, ticks: 12
HIGH, LOW, LOW
Speed for ShiftRightAt: 0, ticks: 135
Speed for shiftlist: 0, ticks: 3850
Speed for arrayCopy: 0, ticks: 998
Speed for MoveValueToFront: 0, ticks: 840
LOW, HIGH, LOW
Speed for ShiftRightAt: 0, ticks: 15
Speed for shiftlist: 0, ticks: 16
Speed for arrayCopy: 0, ticks: 9
Speed for MoveValueToFront: 0, ticks: 39
```

Method of testing: 
https://pastebin.com/HKkixHGR

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: What code you have written for this? What issue you are facing with that code?

Comment: I've tried using a for loop to take the last element and put it up front, and then insert that variable, but I fear that it's not the most efficient nor fastest way.

Comment: Please share what you have tried. Otherwise it looks like a "do my code for me" question

Comment: Turn your `array` into a `list`, save your element to a variable, remove the element from the list, insert it at index 0.

Comment: why don't you use a  List instead? with List you can do smth like this    `list.Insert(list[index],0);  list.RemoveAt(index+1);`

Comment: Added what I've tried in the main topic.
I don't want to use a list because I believes arrays are faster, yes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moving elements in array c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7242909/moving-elements-in-array-c-sharp)

Comment: It seems that you want to swap one element with another on a array?

Comment: @SirJosh3917 not in every case, if you need to maximize perfomance - try to do it in different ways

Comment: After some testing with the 4 below methods, I found these results:

Speed for moveElement: 951, ticks: 4026702
Speed for ShiftRightAt: 18, ticks: 77829
Speed for shiftlist: 44, ticks: 188102
Speed for arrayCopy: 55, ticks: 233153

Comment: After trying it a bit,the fastest method has a difference in performance depending on the element index. Using your test code, but setting the index at 2000000,`Speed for ShiftRightAt: 509, ticks: 1694567
Speed for shiftlist: 198, ticks: 659088`

Comment: I really don't know at this point. Some methods are faster then others in specific scenarios.

Comment: @SirJosh3917 have a look at the edit in my answer. I think its faster now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your nice drawing gives exactly what you need to write.

```
public static void ShiftRightAt<T>(T[] array, int index)
{
    if (index < 0 || index >= array.Length) return; // throw exception

    var element = array[index]; // take out the element

    for (int i = index; i > 0; i--)
    {
        array[i] = array[i - 1];
    }

    array[0] = element;
}
```

Comment: Is this the fastest way possible?
Can Array.Copy do this any faster?

Comment: oh I just noticed your question you already did this. hmm this is fastest way I think (if you don't want to blow up using unsafe)

Comment: I'll gladly use unsafe if it means more speed.

Comment: write your program in c++ if you are looking for speed. that is closer to the metal.

Comment: Really the fastets. Nearly 20 times faster than my "solution"

Answer (score 1):

It's easier using a list. After that, convert it back to an array.

```
var array = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };                 
var list = array.ToList();
list.Remove(3);
list.Insert(0, 3);
array = list.ToArray();
```

Comment: Don't lists consume more resources then an array?

Comment: List uses an Array under the hood, hidden mostly behind some method-base abstractions to do things such as hide unused elements and grow the array when more space is needed. Having a constant size, this will use an array of 2^(ceiling)log2(N), which should be a trivial jump in most cases

Comment: this will be actually slower (while its more readable) than what OPs having

Answer (score 1):

This is an example using `Array.Copy`,so it should be fast enough:

```
int elementAt = 3;
int[] array = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

int[] arr1=new int[array.Length];
arr1[0] = array[elementAt];
Array.Copy(array, 0, arr1, 1, elementAt);
Array.Copy(array, elementAt+1, arr1, elementAt+1, array.Length-elementAt-1);
//arr1={3, 0, 1, 2, 4, 5}
```

**Edit**

I was not satisfied with the results, as i thought the `Array.Copy` should be faster. I think this version improves speed a lot:

```
int saved = array[elementAt];
Array.Copy(array, elementAt + 1, array, elementAt, array.Length - elementAt - 1);
Array.Copy(array, 0, array, 1, array.Length - 1);
array[0] = saved;
```

Comment: using the same testing method ( check OP for method ) here's your results and how you do.

https://pastebin.com/a3Fm2AJZ

Comment: So that's an improvement. It's the faster in some test cases,isn't it?

Comment: Yup. Every solution has their strong scenarios and weak scenarios. For example, you did the best in the case where (LOW, HIGH, LOW, and also HIGH, HIGH, LOW) it's a low amount of iterations, a high index size and low array size.

Comment: Also in (LOW, LOW, LOW - HIGH, HIGH, LOW and LOW, HIGH, HIGH) :)

Comment: For LOW LOW LOW ShiftRightAt wins there at *only* 3 ticks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an extension method that you could use:

```
public static int[] MoveValueToFront(this int[] values, int searchValue)
{
    if (values == null || values.Length == 0)
    {
        return values;
    }

    var rest = values.TakeWhile(v => v != searchValue).ToArray();

    if (rest.Length == values.Length)
    {
        return values;
    }

    values[0] = searchValue;
    rest.CopyTo(values, 1);

    return values;
}
```

Which would allow you to do this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMoverExtension()
{

    var testValues = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    var result = testValues.MoveValueToFront(3);


    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new int[] { 3, 0, 1, 2, 4, 5 }, result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't (or don't want to) work with `List` you could also use the following:

```
public int[] moveElement(int[] array, int index)
{
    int[] save = new int[] { array[index] };
    var rest = array.Take(index).Concat(array.Skip(index + 1));
    return save.Concat(rest).ToArray();
}
```

**EDIT**

If you need this for different data types this is a generic version:

```
public T[] moveElement<T>(T[] array, int index)
{
    T[] save = new T[] { array[index] };
    var rest = array.Take(index).Concat(array.Skip(index + 1));
    return save.Concat(rest).ToArray();
}
```